# Specify the width and height of the Excel Spreadsheet window created with openpyxl

Tags: openpyxl

I want to specify the height and width of the window that opens with a spreadsheet created using openpyxl. There are windowHeight and windowWidth parameters, but I can't figure out how to use them. That is, this:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
wb.save("output.xlsx")
```

Creates this when I open `output.xlsx`:
[image]

And I want it to create this:
[image]

Comment: You can do this with workbook views.

Comment: Hi @CharlieClark. Since there is absolutely no documentation that I can find on this, nor any sample code on the Internet, would you be willing to modify my code to make it do what I want and post the example? I can then accept your answer! I would be super-appreciative!

Comment: What code? The documentation is the OOXML specification. But basically you can reverse engineer this from an existing file as openpyxl preserves and exposes all the relevant elements.